# CSS: An incomplete circle with a border where the color depends on percentage

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to reproduce this design:

[image]

It's a circle where a piece is cut out off (at the bottom), and where, based on a percentage, you fill in the border with a color. I came across a couple of solutions (below), but none seem to handle a combination of the two. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

The solutions I came across:

1. [CSS animate circle border filling with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385924/css-animate-circle-border-filling-with-color) (it gives a solution, but for a complete circle)
2. [How to make not fully rounded circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193140/how-to-make-not-fully-rounded-circle) (it provides a solution for a circle with a hole in it, but not on how to do the percentage)

Comment: hey @tilly please upload your code in jsfiddle , then i will better help you

Comment: Please include your code in your question, not in an external site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with how to do this. Also plese include information on where the percentage is coming from - is there some javascript?